# SNMPD only system group available!

Tags: snmp

I installed at fedora snmpd package...

```
> view    systemview    included  
> .1.3.6.1.2.1.1 view    systemview   
> included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.1 view   
> all          included   .1 80
> ####
> # Finally, grant the group read-only access to the systemview view.
> 
> #       group          context sec.model sec.level prefix read  
> write  notif access  notConfigGroup ""
> any       noauth    exact  systemview
> none none access  notConfigGroup ""   
> any       noauth    exact  all  none
> none
```

I could get only system information.... using snmpwalk or whatever..

I tried adding RFC 1213 1.3.6.1.2.11 snmp node with no luck....
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default fedora config is designed to only let you see the system group for security purposes.  You need to replace the config with a better set that lets you access everything on the device.  Running `snmpconf -g basic_setup` can help you with getting started.  Or, you can replace the file with the following snippet (based on the above, I **believe** you aren't using SNMPv3 and only using the insecure SNMPv1 or SNMPv2c, so this is designed for that):

```
rocommunity ChoseACommunity
```

Make sure you set `ChooseACommunity` to something uniquely yours.

Comment: thank you.. it was configuration problem :( didnt know..